How do I code Gradient Descent over a discrete Probability Function in Pytorch?
I am trying to code a gradient descent algorithm to minimize the Shannon entropy of a convolution between a 1D array X and a smaller 1D array A, where the parameters to optimize for are the entries of A. However, to compute the entropy, I need to first compute the discrete probability of the distribution. This is, however, breaking the gradient calculation inside of PyTorch I believe.
Here is my Loss Function:
def loss_function(A):
    return Shentropy(F.conv1d(padded_input, A.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0), padding=0))

def Shentropy(wf):
    unique_elements, counts = wf.unique(return_counts=True)
    entrsum = 0
    for x in counts:
        p = x/len(wf) #Calculates probability of x
        entrsum-= p*torch.log2(p) #Shannon's Entropy Formula        
    return entrsum

This, however, gives me the following error:
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
I have tried swapping wf.unique(return_counts=True) with wf.softmax(dim=0), and the code does run that way. However, softmax does not work with the entropy formula (gives wrong results).
Is there an alternative way to make this differentiable so to not break the gradient or compromise the formula? Or perhaps I should use a "discrete gradient" of sorts?
